# Default constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the MDN, it is mentioned that if we don't specify a constructor method, a default constructor is used.

For base classes, the default constructor is:

```
constructor() {}
```

For derived classes, the default constructor is:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

Why derived classes default constructor has rest parameters (...args) and base class default constructor does not have?

Comment: Variable amount of arguments for the superclass constructor, it passes the arguments to super. `...` means a varying amount.

Comment: "Why derived classes default constructor has rest parameters (...args) and base class default constructor does not have? " - because they would have no effect anyways?

Comment: base class is `Object.prototype` and the it's `constructor` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: This seems like a question to ask the author of that MDN post, not on stack overflow

Comment: Default constructor is noop. It is no concern of children classes if parent class has noop or op constructor, they should just play safe.

Answer (score 0):

In that exact situation the `..args` seems superfluous, but you should consider the case when the base object is not `Object`. In this case, it is perfectly reasonable to call the super constructor with the arguments.

So, let's assume there are the classes `A` and `B`. `A` does have a constuctor defined explicitely, `B` does not, but `A` is the superclass of `B`. In this case if you invoke `new B(myArg)`, it is logical to invoke the `constructor` of `A`.